# How to install proper Angular CLI version

Tags: angular

I am updating Angular 13 -> 14. Everything went fine but now i have weird problem with angular CLI. When I am trying to run ng serve it gives me an error:

[image]

but my CLI version is already 14.0.2. I was trying to run `npm uninstall @angular/cli` and then install it again, delete node modeules and run `npm install` but with no result.

[image]

What is tricky, when i delete my local version of angular CLI and install it globally by `npm intall -g @angular/cli` it is working fine.

pacakge.json

```
{
  "name": "ctnb-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "npm run lint && npm run test && ng build --configuration development",
    "build:prod": "npm run lint && npm run test && ng build --configuration production",
    "build:stage": "npm run lint && npm run test && ng build --configuration stage",
    "watch": "npm run lint && ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "extract": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src/app --output ./src/app/i18n/*.json --clean --sort --format namespaced-json",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,ts,html}\" --quiet --fix",
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint",
    "pre-push": "ng test --watch=false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "14.0.2",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~14.0.3",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "^1.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.3",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^13.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "flag-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^13.1.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.0.3",
    "@bartholomej/ngx-translate-extract": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.47",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.11.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "loaders.css": "0.1.2",
    "prettier": "^2.6.1",
    "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^2.3.4",
    "typescript": "~4.7.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Comment: Problem was caused by "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.1.0".
Update @angular-builders/custom-webpack to 14.0.0 solved my issue.